# How to generate uniformly distributed subintervals of an interval?

Tags: python, algorithm, random, distribution

I have a non-empty integer interval *[a; b)*. I want to generate a random non-empty integer subinterval *[c; d)* (where *a <= c* and *d <= b*). The *[c; d)* interval must be uniformly distributed in the sense that every point in *[a; b)* must be equally likely to end up in *[c; d)*.

I tried generating uniformly distributed *c* from *[a; b - 1)*, and then uniformly distributed *d* from *[c + 1; b)*, like this:

```
a = -100
b = 100

N = 10000
cs = np.random.randint(a, b - 1, N)
ds = np.random.randint(cs + 1, b)
```

But when measuring how often each point ends up being sampled, the the distribution is clearly non-unifrom:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hist = np.zeros(b - a, int)
for c, d in zip(cs, ds):
    hist[c - a:d - a] += 1

plt.plot(np.arange(a, b), hist)
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram]

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you divide the range `[a,b)` into N sections, and then select one of those sections at random, then the chance of selecting each point is uniform -- `1/N`.  *It doesn't matter how you divide the range*.

Here's a solution along those lines that uses a pretty uniform selection of division points.

```py
from random import randint

a, b, N = -100, 100, 1000000

intervals = []
while len(intervals) < N:
    # divide the range into 3 intervals [a,x), [x,y), and [y,b)
    # the distributions of the division points don't change the histogram
    # we're careful here to make sure none of them are empty
    p1 = randint(a+1,b-2)
    p2 = randint(a+1,b-2)
    x = min(p1,p2)
    y = max(p1,p2)+1

    # select one at random
    intervals.append([(a,x),(x,y),(y,b)][randint(0,2)])
```

Comment: This is quite clever.

Comment: I'm kicking myself for thinking the segments needed to be equal-sized. Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way `cs` and `ds` are being created is what is messing up the distribution as it's adding bias. Because the range of possible d values depends on c, it results in a non-uniform distribution

Instead, generate subintervals by randomly selecting start and end points, ensuring each subinterval is equally likely. For each start point `c`, any end point `d` within `[c+1, b]` is possible, effectively randomizing subinterval selection

A cleaner way to achieve this could look like

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a, b, N = -100, 100, 10000

# random start and end points for subintervals, ensuring they are sorted
starts_ends = np.sort(np.random.randint(a, b, (N, 2)), axis=1)
# Extract start (c) and end (d) points
cs, ds = starts_ends[:,0], starts_ends[:,1]

# store frequency counts
hist = np.zeros(b - a)

# count occurrences within each subinterval
for c, d in zip(cs, ds):
    hist[c-a:d-a] += 1

plt.plot(np.arange(a, b), hist)
plt.title("Points in Selected Subintervals")
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: Good point, but I want the distribution to be uniform (the plot to be a flat horizontal line), not merely unbiased.